# Travel visa for Mozambique for Canadian and UK citizens?

Tags: visas, uk-citizens, canadian-citizens, mozambique

Hi I am Canadian and will be travelling in South Africa and then travelling by car to Mozambique for a few days. I checked websites but am still confused about the visa process for Mozambique - I have a friend travelling with me who is from the UK - we need to know what to do about getting a visitors visa - can anyone help?

Comment: Several fairly contradictory findings, unfortunately. One site says citizens of countries with Moz. Embassies are not eligible for visa-on-arrival, some say they are. The High Commission of the Republic of Mozambique to the UK doesn't indicate that VoA is authorized. It does look like you'll be able to get one, but your friend will need an advance visa issued.

Answer (score 4):

The Foreign Office contains this advice...

> British nationals need a visa to enter Mozambique. Those travelling
>   for work purposes must obtain a work or business visa before
>   travelling.
>
> Tourists may be able to get a single-entry visa valid for 30 days on
>   arrival. However, there have been reports of visitors being refused
>   this service and being turned back from border posts and airports. It
>   is therefore much safer to get a visa before you leave the UK. You
>   must present on entry a return air ticket (for air travellers) and
>   either an invitation from family / friends or a confirmed hotel
>   reservation.

Source: [Mozambique Travel Advisory (UK Foreign Office)](https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/mozambique/entry-requirements)

The Government of Canada offers this advice...

> Canadians must also be in possession of a visa.
>
> Tourist visa: Required Business visa: Required Student visa: Required
>   Residency/employment visa: Required Transit visa: Required
>
> Tourist visas can be purchased from the Embassy of Mozambique in
>   Washington, D.C. (single- or multiple-entry). While single-entry visas
>   can also be purchased from any point of entry, including airports and
>   border crossings, they are increasingly difficult to obtain. It is
>   strongly recommended that you obtain a visa before arriving in
>   Mozambique. There are reports of travellers being sent back upon entry
>   for not having a visa when they are arriving from a country where
>   there is a Mozambique diplomatic post

Source: [Travel Advice and Advisories (Government of Canada)](http://travel.gc.ca/destinations/mozambique)

Despite the text informing that Canadians can receive a visa at an 'entry point', they indicate the chances of getting bounced.

**Summary:**  Based upon what's written by their respective governments, both Canadian and British nationals should get a visa in advance of travel.  Both nationalities have the additional option of playing 'immigration roulette' at the airport.